# I got db.update() value 1 but when i fetch all the data from database, None of the row was affected in SQLIte database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update answer value when user select item in recylerview. I am storing answer value in zero(Not selectd) and one(selected) form. In recylerview adpater I printed `db.update()` return value and it shows 1. but when i fetch all the data from table, none of the row value was updatated. It bother me a lot. Can anybody please help me?

This is my RecylerviewAdapter Constructor where i initialized databaseHelper

```
public SurveyAnswerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SurveyAnswerModel> 
         arrayList, OnDragStartListener dragStartListener,
         Bundle bundle, OnCountSizeDoneListener onCountSizeDoneListener) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
    this.bundle = bundle;
    countList = new ArrayList<>();
    mOnCountSizeDoneListener = onCountSizeDoneListener;
    databaseHelper = new AnswerHelperSqlite(context);
}
```

This is my RecylerviewAdpater class onClick method

```
holder.btnAns.setTag(position);
holder.btnAns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  selectedPosition = (int) view.getTag();
  if (bundle.getBoolean("MultiSelectionAllow")) {


surveyAnswerModel.setIsSelected(!surveyAnswerModel.getIsSelected());
      if (surveyAnswerModel.getIsSelected()) {

         holder.btnAns.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
         R.drawable.button_corner_with_background));

         holder.btnAns.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
         R.color.white));
         surveyAnswerModel.setIsSelected(true);

         } else {

         holder.btnAns.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
         R.drawable.button_round_corner));

         holder.btnAns.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
         R.color.chronic_acne_blue));
         surveyAnswerModel.setIsSelected(false);          
              }
    } else {
          surveyAnswerModel.setIsSelected(true);

          holder.btnAns.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
          R.drawable.button_corner_with_background));
          holder.btnAns.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
          R.color.white));
            if (row_index > -1) {
             SurveyAnswerModel model = arrayList.get(row_index);
             model.setIsSelected(false);                 


holder.btnAns.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, 
            R.drawable.button_round_corner));

            holder.btnAns.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
            R.color.chronic_acne_blue));
            }
            row_index = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

  databaseHelper.updateValue(arrayList.get(position).getId(), 
  arrayList.get(position).getIsSelected() ? 1 : 0)

  Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.e("after updte ansID", "" + cursor.getString(0));
                Log.e(" after updte isselect", "" + 
               Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(3)));
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my AnswerHelperDB  class for SQLite

```
public class AnswerHelperSqlite {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "answer.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbanswer";
public static final String ANSWER_ID = "id";
public static final String ANSWER = "answer";
public static final String ANSWER_TYPE = "type";
public static final String ANSWER_VALUE = "value";
public static final String SURVEY_STEP_ID = "surveyStepId";
public static final String IS_SELECT = "isSelected";
private Answer openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public AnswerHelperSqlite(Context context) {
    openHelper = new Answer(context);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void saveCategoryRecord(int id, String answer, int surveyId, int 
isSelect) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ANSWER_ID, id);
    contentValues.put(ANSWER, answer);
    contentValues.put(SURVEY_STEP_ID, surveyId);
    contentValues.put(IS_SELECT, isSelect);
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public int updateValue(int ansId, int isSelect) {

    Log.e("update isselect", "" + isSelect);
    Log.e("update id", "" + ansId);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(IS_SELECT, isSelect);

    return database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "id = ?", new String[] 
 {String.valueOf(ansId)});
}

public Cursor getISselectById(String surveyID) {
    String[] surveyIDs = {surveyID};

    return database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                    IS_SELECT},
            SURVEY_STEP_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{surveyID},
            null, null, null, null);

}


public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
    return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
}

private class Answer extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Answer(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ANSWER_ID + " 
                 INTEGER,"
                + ANSWER + " TEXT,"
                + SURVEY_STEP_ID + " INTEGER,"
                + IS_SELECT + " INTEGER )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
          newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: If update() returns 1 then this means 1 row was updated, even with the same previous value. So if the previous value was 1 and you update the row with the value 1 the update will be done and update() will return 1 (because 1 row was updated even with the same old value). Now if the new value is 0 and update() returns 1 this means that the new value 0 is now stored in that row and if you can't see it then you are not looking at the actual data of the table.

Comment: Thank you for response. But i have only one table in my database and i print the log when user select the answers it shows true. and update() returns 1 but after updating data into table i show all data and none of the row value is changed.

Comment: If you are sure that update() returns 1 (in your code there is not any logging of the returned value though) then the row is updated 100%. If you can't see that updated value then you are doing something wrong in the process of fetching the rows.

Comment: Here is my log     E/isSelected: true
E/ans id: 72
E/ans isSelect: true
E/update isselect: 1
E/update id: 72
E/updtate return val: 1    this is value return by db.update()

Comment: E/After Update: update
E/after updte ansID: 69
E/ after updte isselect: false
E/after updte ansID: 70
E/ after updte isselect: false
E/after updte ansID: 72     
E/ after updte isselect: false    here is my value which should be updated after calling db.update() but its not working

Comment: Here is code to fetch data from table after db.update() call.                                              Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getTimeRecordList();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.e("after updte ansID", "" + cursor.getString(0));
                    Log.e(" after updte isselect", "" + Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(3)));
                }